# Render a html file in Django

Tags: python, django

I read the document about django tutorial.
Now I want to read my html and display it.
So I start a project and start a app **myapp_page**.
The folder structure is blow.

[image]

I render my html file in the views. There is "Hello world" in this html file.

[image]

I set the path in the **urls.py**.

[image]

And I add the folder path in the **settings.py**.

[image]

But the html didn't show in the 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp_page/

How to display my custom html file?

How does the django manage the path?

I am confuse.

Answer (score 3):

Rename your **template** directory to **templates** change it in `settings.py` too, this is optional.

In `views.py` change the line to `return render(request, 'myapp_page.html')`

> Note the return function added.

You do not need to specify `templates/` dir again because Django knows it and starts looking from its (directory's root)

Comment: Thanks, if I want to define the "template" folder, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to template. I suggested it because docs refer them and by default Django in apps sees template**s** directory. If the solution works please consider accepting it.